# Is it true that right click means click the left mouse button?

Tags: windows, input

I came across this [MSDN document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg153549(v=vs.85).aspx). I was surprised and looked up the terms but I found *right click* is clicking the right mouse button.

> Left-handed users often find it more comfortable to swap the functions of the left and right buttons—using the right button as the pointer, and the left button to show the context menu. For this reason, the Windows help documentation uses the terms primary button and secondary button, which refer to logical function rather than physical placement. In the default (right-handed) setting, the left button is the primary button and the right is the secondary button. *However, the terms right click and left click refer to logical actions. **Right clicking** means clicking the primary button, whether that button is physically on the right or left side of the mouse.*

Does the document use the terms incorrectly?

Comment: The answers is already in the description, right-clicking for left-handed have a different meaning. so in general, right-clicking means the button where you open the right-click popup with. Though this kind of question is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: My point is I’ve known for a long time that right clicking is clicking the right mouse button (secondary button). And I looked up the term; right clicking is clicking the right button (secondary). I’ll clarify my question.

Comment: It's clearly a misprint. *In the default (right-handed) setting, the left button is the primary button and the right is the secondary button.* this is what they are trying to convey, in the followup they got the terminology mixed up.